# DBMS Performance-Tuning Book Recommendations

Tags: sql-server, database, performance

Anyone have any recommendations for books about performance tuning on either frontend or backend? I'm looking specifically for asp.net or sql (MS-SQL) performance tuning, but anything is good to go. Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server is what I use and am most interested in, but any would do, I'm sure.

Comment: I find most performance tuning information on the web in the form of articles/blogs/...  The particular software vendor usually has forums for discussing such topics, as a focused book does not always make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you visited [SQL Server Performance](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/)? 
Take a look at their [Books section](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/books/index.aspx), you'll find a lot of books, a of them lot reviewed.

Comment: Nice site. And it seems they reviewed some books I was looking at. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent [free ebook "Dissecting SQL Server Execution Plans" by Grant Fritchey](http://www.red-gate.com/specials/grant.htm) available from Redgate.
 Awesome free resource for SQL Server performance tuning.

Comment: Sweet! This will definitely get me started. Thanks! :}

Answer (score 0):

I thought Professional SQL Server 2005 Performance Tuning by WROX was pretty excellent.

Answer (score 0):

[Performance Tuning Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) on Microsoft Technet.

Answer (score -1):

[http://www.amazon.com/Server-Performance-Tuning-Distilled-Experts/dp/1430219025/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1255025248&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219025)